# Android SD card writing fails, but not consistently

Tags: android

I've got a pretty thorny problem with Android 2.3: I have an app that gathers various logs for debugging and support purposes ([my company](http://www.sdgsystems.com) does Linux for rugged hardware), and has stopped working lately, because it's failing to write to the SD card. Here are the symptoms I've seen and the investigations I've carried out:

- Happens across multiple devices of multiple types with different SD cards, all of which have been checked for filesystem corruption (no issues found).
- All devices report: Environment.getExternalStorageState() equals Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.
- All devices also report that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().canWrite() is false.
- Via PackageManager.checkPermission(), my app reports that it has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
- OI File Manager is able to create directories and move files on the SD card; my app can do neither.

This code is sufficient to cause a failure:

```
String sdcardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File directory = new File(sdcardDirectory + "/logger");  
if(!directory.mkdirs()){  
    //fails here.  
    Log.w("Logger", "Could not create logger directory.");  
}
```

Since I have access to the keys for this device, I even went so far as to sign the app with the platform key and run it as android.uid.system, with no luck. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Post the code you're using to try and write to teh external SD

Comment: Gah. I'll just edit it into the original post.

Comment: if you "adb shell" on your device, can you create files/dirs there? does "ls -la" show you that files / folders in the sd card directory have the right permissions? `-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1015            0 Mar 13 14:18 file` `drwxrwxrwx    2 1000     1015         4096 Mar 13 14:19 folder` is what I get. Those numbers (1000 and 1015) are also important and are required for the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission (1015 is a group in linux that every app gets member of when it has that permission).

Comment: Never use concatenation to create paths. Always use the proper `File` constructor. In this case, `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "logger")` will be more reliable.

Comment: Permissions are correct, shell file-fiddling works fine, file managers function as described.

Comment: +1 for CommonsWare. Never hardcode separators. Use `File.pathSeparator` or `File.separatorChar` if you really need them.

Comment: "All devices also report that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().canWrite() is false" Then how do you pretend to create a folder there?

Comment: That's the problem-- Android reports I have permissions to write (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED, as opposed to Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY, or whatever that constant's called), but I actually don't.

Comment: Maybe the folder already exists, or maybe you need to be root to write there. In any case is bad practice to write in SDCard root. Try `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` instead.

Comment: The application is running as root already.

Comment: About the consistency: I've not understood if you mean for a given device and SDCard, the app has worked fine and now fails (behavior based on time); or the app works on some devices of certain brands but not for others (behavior based on device model). If it were the first, as you are logging and those files tend to be get really big, maybe you are appending to an already existent file and it has grown too much bigger than the OS or filesystem allows?

Comment: The logs are output from logcat and some other handy stuff we can use when our devices go out into the field, so they shouldn't be overwhelmingly big-- I'm pretty sure logcat and dmesg come from ring buffers, and the other files I'm capturing are fixed-length and small.

Re: consistency, the application worked on all of the devices I have on my desk on 2.1. We're near the end of our 2.3 port, and as I understand it, it hasn't ever worked on 2.3.

Comment: 2.3? Go ICS :) What target version do you specify for your app? there might be some workarounds enabled for apps targeting older api levels. Have you tried if a clean re-install of the app helps? Is your app running inside a different app or using customized process ids (manifest). If you create a new blank app that does just what you want does that work?

Comment: Current state of the art for rugged data collection hardware is the Marvell PXA320. It's a minor miracle we have 2.3 running with acceptable performance, much less ICS, as much as we'd like to move forward. :P Starting a new project and moving the source over is my next step-- it's possible something's changed and rebuilding the project isn't catching that.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a case partly of bad diagnosis on my part, and partly an apparent change in 2.1 to 2.3.

The bad diagnosis was that the directory above was indeed being created. The apparent change between 2.1 and 2.3 may be Android internally, or it may be the way we're setting up paths, PATH, and symbolic links in our own builds. Further down from the code in the original post, there are a few calls to exec() to get e.g. output from logcat and copies of various bits of useful information in /proc; using absolute paths to the commands fixed the problem.

Thanks for the help in ruling things out.